# Nestjs v5.0.0 passport affect to all routes

Tags: jwt, passport.js, nestjs

I am updating my code to v5 and I would like to have a ward which affect to all routes as I had in my last code, but I don't know how to do that in the new version. I attach my old code.

```
    @Module({
        components: [AuthService, JwtStrategy, Config],
        controllers: [AuthenticateController],
    })
    
    export class AuthModule implements NestModule {
        

public configure(consumer: MiddlewaresConsumer) {
        consumer
            .apply(passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }))
            .forRoutes({ path: '*', method: RequestMethod.ALL });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/666) are the solution of the problem